# What Star Trek episode has a ship twisted by a wormhole?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

I have watched almost all episodes of all *Star Trek* TV series, but I am unable to recall this scene:

[image: Star Trek - Wormhole warping]

In the image, I can clearly see a Warp Nacelle which is twisted/warped by a wormhole or something.

Comment: Where did you find the image?

Comment: That looks more like fan art than a screenshot from an episode.

Comment: @Wikis Its in circulation in my Whatsapp groups (tracking back to source is close to impossible) and everyone is asking me.

Comment: It does look like fanart/someone took an image of that ship and distorted it themselves in a Photoshop type program. Look at the top left part of the picture- there's a clear seam/line in the sky and clouds, probably the top of the original undistorted image.

Comment: @TrishLing - I was thinking that. My photoshop skills aren't sufficient to un-twist it.

Comment: @Trish Sounds rationale. But, production team also uses digital effects. They don't shoot such things with cam.

Comment: Yes, but usually professionally made images don't have such obvious seams.

Comment: @Trish Don't forget they are old. Today a kid can produce a better graphics than that of ST:TOS, for example.

Comment: @Richard You need to use the warp tool...

Comment: @kapep - Hehe. Warp speed, Mr Kapep.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've located the original image.  This ship is a concept art of the **USS Archer**, designed by senior *Star Trek* illustrator [Rick Sternbach](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rick_Sternbach) and [hand-drawn by Yoshi Vu](https://axanarproductions.com/fan-film-friday-the-history-of-star-trek-renegades-part-3-2014-2015/) for the [*Star Trek Renegades*](http://renegades.show/home/) fan series.

[image: concept art of spaceship]

As such, this image is not a canon production. It appears that the original image has been distorted by another (unnamed) fan.

Major hat tip to **@kapep** for untwisting it.

Comment: And there's another pic here of the same ship; https://www.facebook.com/STRtheSeries/photos/a.514444175253647.122097.514118728619525/853818067982921/?type=1

Comment: I didn't know it was upside down :D I've just used the photoshop polar coordinates filter in case anyone wonders.

Comment: @kapep - You did great work here. It's only because I'm a colossal trek nerd that I immediately thought "well, that's inverted".

Comment: That is one fine-looking ship.

Comment: For the record, the background is a [stock image](https://web.archive.org/web/20110617150851/http://www.altel.elk.pl/pliki/Idylla.bmp).

Answer (score 27):

This is not from any canon production.  As has been discovered by other Experts, this is fan art - Art created by someone who was a designer for the series, but for a non-canon project.  The rest of the post will remain in tact for historical reasons.

---

It should be noted that while the image is of a Sovereign class ship, it is not a particularly good one.  There are errors.  But the intersection of the primary and secondary hulls eliminate Intrepid class as a possibility for this ship.  This is obviously fan art.

Another factor that prevents this from being Voyager is the lack of the Aeroshuttle on the underside of the primary hull, lack of the impulse engines on the nacelle pylons, the shape and color of the main deflector, and the addition of Dominion War era escape pods in a loose formation on the hull (they were more tightly arranged on the intrepid).

A key factor in identifying this as fan art is the low quality of the color of the image, lack of film grain (which while the ship was digital, the movies were mastered to film, and have film grain, at least in every version I have seen of them, including blu-ray), general low polygon count, incorrect nacelles and Bussard collectors, and the amateurish warping of the image.  While not definitive by any means, the aspect ratio is not even close to the ones used in any of the films - the image has, at least in that respect, definitely been doctored.

Comment: Are you sure about the Sovereign-class? Looks like Intrepid-class (USS Voyager) to me. Still, I agree that it is most likely fanart.

Comment: The intersection of the primary and secondary hulls are all wrong.  It is smooth in the intrepid, and staggered (as shown) in the sovereign.

Comment: The front of the nacelle doesn't match Enterprise E.    I would add that this is obviously fan art.

Comment: BTW, reverse image search didn't find it.   But Google does think it looks like the Manet of a cow.  http://www.oilpainting-frame.com/upload1/file-admin/images/new8/Edouard%20Manet-298263.jpg

Comment: I can't see the posted image for some reason, but is it possible it's from Star Trek Online or some other video game?  In STO, you can customize your ship with bits and pieces from other variants of the same basic design.

Comment: Star Trek: the Motion Picture had the Enterprise sucked into a wormhole... but it was not twisted; the effect looked more like the image being dragged.  http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Wormhole_effect

Comment: Here is the untwisted images: http://i.imgur.com/cNhi0Yf.png Still no reverse image search result though.

Comment: @kapep - Amazing work. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

As many of the other answers have already pointed out, the image posted is a fan art image.

However, at the title of the question I immediately thought of the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "[Twisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))", in which an unknown energy field distorts the ship, and I thought I would mention it here in case anyone else was thinking of it or may find it useful.

I cannot find an image of the ship distorted from the outside, but here's a schematic of what the ship "looked like" to the people on board:

[image: twisted schematic]

And the bar Sandrines, looking a little less than stellar:

[image: distorted image of a bar]

Comment: It should be noted that the Sandrines picture is the only example of its kind throughout the episode. The rest of the episode consists of utterly un-distorted rooms whose doors are just magically connected to different rooms than usual.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it is fan art as both the radial fade that is the focal point of the background and the twist effect that is on the ship are both distinct features of the graphical editor Paint.NET - a professional wouldn't have left them so obviously recognizable.

Additionally, I believe the ship image is from a Sketchup Model.

Comment: Why on the Earth would ship image from Sketchup Model?